# Installing GVM using Cygwin - Proxy Issues

Tags: bash, curl, proxy, cygwin

I have Cygwin installed, however the following command

```
curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash
```

does not work.

The proxy is preventing that command from working, however I don't know what command I'd run beforehand to get that curl statement above to work.

Do I use the following?

```
curl -x or curl --proxy
```

Where do I enter my username and password at?  I am new to the commands, and I looked them up however, I can't figure where I am supposed to enter my usrname/password.

Could someone please help me with what I need to do?  Thanks, this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You know the right flags so, from man page curl:

```
-x, --proxy <[protocol://][user:password@]proxyhost[:port]>
```

you can also use `--proxy-user`

```
curl -x http://proxy_server:proxy_port --proxy-user username:password -L <the url>
```

use version which is avialbale for you in cygwin

Comment: What would <the url> stand for in the second example?  -L is redirects, correct?  Do I need that?

Comment: `-L` stands for location, so your URL

Comment: Ok, I don't have access to my environment properties, and cygwin keeps giving me the following issue: "GVM: JAVA_HOME not set and cannot find javac to deduce location, please set JAVA_HOME." By chance would you know how to set JAVA_HOME through cygwin?

Comment: One problem per question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have cygwin installed, and trying to follow the steps located at http://gvmtool.net/ using the following steps instead if you are dealing with a proxy to install grails.

1. Use this command **$ curl -v -x PROXY:PROXY PORT -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -s get.gvmtool.net | bash** instead of **$ curl -s get.gvmtoo.net | bash**
2. **$gvm help**
3. **$gvm install grails** or **gvm install grails 2.3.8** (this was newest version at time)

Once installation is done, you will be complete.  If you get some error saying FILE CORRUPT, basically saying the version couldn't be installed.  You will have to re-install CYGWIN, and when you get to *Select Packages* section, search for "ZIP", and KEEP everything.  Once you do that, the steps above will work.