# installing gvm in cygwin using proxy

Tags: curl, proxy, cygwin, gvm

I have tried all the answers provided in [Installing GVM using Cygwin - Proxy Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542789/installing-gvm-using-cygwin-proxy-issues) to no avail. I have tried other variations as well. Not sure what I might be missing. Console below. Password in tics for special characters. Ideas?

```
[~]$curl -v -x {myproxy}:80 -u {myusername}:'{mypassword}' get.gvmtool.net | bash
-bash: $'\302\226curl': command not found
[~]$ curl -v -x {myproxy}:80 -u {myusername}:'{mypassword}' get.gvmtool.net | bash
-bash: $'\302\226curl': command not found
[~]$ curl -v -x {myproxy}:80 -L get.gvmtool.net | bash
-bash: $'\302\226curl': command not found
[~]$ curl -v -x {myproxy}:80 get.gvmtool.net | bash
-bash: $'\302\226curl': command not found
[~]$ curl -v -x {myproxy} get.gvmtool.net | bash
-bash: $'\302\226curl': command not found
[~]$ curl -v -x http://{myproxy} get.gvmtool.net | bash
-bash: $'\302\226curl': command not found
[~]$ curl -v -x http://{myusername}:'{mypassword}'@{myproxy} get.gvmtool.net | bash
-bash: $'\302\226curl': command not found
[~]$ curl -v -x http://{myusername}:'{mypassword}'@{myproxy} -L get.gvmtool.net | bash
-bash: $'\302\226curl': command not found
```

Comment: See [this issue on github](https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/115).

Comment: Looks like get.gvmtool.net no longer exists.  Now replaced by http://sdkman.io ( http://get.sdkman.io/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, pak. for anybody coming across this, the answer was to actually type in the command. i must have been cutting and pasting.

```
[uc164033@UC164033-TPD-A ~]$ curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash
bash: line 1: HTTP/1.1: No such file or directory
bash: line 2: Server:: command not found
bash: line 3: Date:: command not found
bash: line 4: Connection:: command not found
bash: line 5: Content-Type:: command not found
bash: line 6: Content-Length:: command not found
bash: line 7: Via:: command not found
bash: line 8: $'\r': command not found

Thanks for using

_____/\\\\\\\\\\\\__/\\\________/\\\__/\\\\____________/\\\\_
 ___/\\\//////////__\/\\\_______\/\\\_\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\_
  __/\\\_____________\//\\\______/\\\__\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_
   _\/\\\____/\\\\\\\__\//\\\____/\\\___\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\_
    _\/\\\___\/////\\\___\//\\\__/\\\____\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\_
     _\/\\\_______\/\\\____\//\\\/\\\_____\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_
      _\/\\\_______\/\\\_____\//\\\\\______\/\\\_____________\/\\\_
       _\//\\\\\\\\\\\\/_______\//\\\_______\/\\\_____________\/\\\_
        __\////////////__________\///________\///______________\///__

                                       Will now attempt installing...

Looking for a previous installation of GVM...
Looking for unzip...
Looking for curl...
Looking for sed...
Installing gvm scripts...
Create distribution directories...
Create candidate directories...
Created for HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Date: Tue: /home/uc164033/.gvm/HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Date: Tue
Created for  23 Dec 2014 20:45:14 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 91
Via: 1.1 vegur

crash: /home/uc164033/.gvm/ 23 Dec 2014 20:45:14 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 91
Via: 1.1 vegur

crash
Created for gaiden: /home/uc164033/.gvm/gaiden
Created for glide: /home/uc164033/.gvm/glide
Created for gradle: /home/uc164033/.gvm/gradle
Created for grails: /home/uc164033/.gvm/grails
Created for griffon: /home/uc164033/.gvm/griffon
Created for groovy: /home/uc164033/.gvm/groovy
Created for groovyserv: /home/uc164033/.gvm/groovyserv
Created for jbake: /home/uc164033/.gvm/jbake
Created for lazybones: /home/uc164033/.gvm/lazybones
Created for springboot: /home/uc164033/.gvm/springboot
Created for vertx: /home/uc164033/.gvm/vertx
Prime the config file...
Download script archive...
Extract script archive...
Cygwin detected - normalizing paths for unzip...
warning [C:\cygwin64\home\uc164033\.gvm\tmp\res-2.2.0.zip]:  166 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
Install scripts...
Attempt update of bash profiles...
Updated existing /home/uc164033/.bash_profile
Updated existing /home/uc164033/.profile
Updated existing /home/uc164033/.bashrc
Attempt update of zsh profiles...
Created and initialised /home/uc164033/.zshrc



All done!


Please open a new terminal, or run the following in the existing one:

    source "/home/uc164033/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"

Then issue the following command:

    gvm help

Enjoy!!!
```